# magento dropdown menus not working

Tags: magento

The admin on our magento site has suddenly stopped working. The only clickable option is the dashboard button. I have seen others query this but no solution is visible that I can see. I have checked permission for folders and files. It was working fine. I added a piece of script into the headers script within system>design after that I was going to change a banner but could not get to it because the admin menu stopped working. Is there anything I can check?

Comment: have use any jQuery in admin panel.

Comment: I have not changed anything in the admin panel in weeks apart from add a verified by badge in the design menu

Comment: have you change anything in the `prototype.js`

Comment: No changes in the prototype.js

Comment: Check browser console whether the js files are loading or not.I have faced similar issue.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of errors

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to check whether it is due to js conflict:

- Install firebug in your firefox browser (if not installed).
- Open the url in firefox and press f12.
- Click on console and then refresh the page.
- If there is any js specific error, then it is either due to incorrect js file include path or js code conflict.

Let me know what error you are getting.

Comment: ReferenceError: Fieldset is not defined
 

$('footer_bug_tracking').target = 'Varien_External';

/index...2831d7/ (line 1068)
ReferenceError: Translate is not defined
 

var Translator = new Translate([]);

/index...2831d7/ (line 71)
ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
 

...= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]; // f...

/index...2831d7/ (line 77)
ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined
 

To put a few down

Comment: I think you are using jquery in your website, and it is conflicting with Magento's prototype.js

Comment: any suggestions to prevent happening again?

Comment: use jQuery.noConflict(); whenever you use jQuery with prototype.js

Answer (score 1):

In your Data base run 
select * from 'core_config_data' where path='dev/js/merge_files'

in that change the value is 1 to 0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think it is solved. I have copied from fresh magento files the JS folder overwriting what was on the site and also made sure all permissions are set correctly. This seemed to have done the job but came across a few other errors with orders which is not related to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but very different situation.

I did not put / in base_url, so magento was unable to find the JavaScript files.

Use

```
n98-magerun.phar config:set web/unsecure/base_url http://local.website.com/
```

NOT

```
n98-magerun.phar config:set web/unsecure/base_url http://local.website.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of merging js files, so on dashboard of magento you cannot access that js merging settings. so try to fix this issue on PhpMyadmin side,

go and search "dev/js/merge_files" on the "core_config_data" table.